# The service cannot accept control messages at this time

Tags: iis, windows-7-x64

I just stopped an Application Pool in IIS. When trying to start it, IIS complains that,

> The service cannot accept control messages at this time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080425).

**What gives? [Whence](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/whence) did this error come?**

Looking at the Event Viewer > System shows these warnings:

> A worker process '1456' serving application pool 'MyAppPool' failed to stop a listener channel for protocol 'http' in the allotted time.  The data field contains the error number.
>
> A process serving application pool 'MyAppPool' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '10592'. The data field contains the error number.
>
> A process serving application pool 'MyAppPool' exceeded time limits during shut down. The process id was '10516'.

This resolved itself after about 5-minutes, at which point we tried to restart the website, and received:

> The World Wide Web Publish Service (W3SVC) is stopped. Web sites cannot be started unless the World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC) is running.

So, we started the W3SVC service, and then we could start our website.

Comment: Check Visual Studio , If debugger is attached and the process is in debugging mode.Or else go to Local Services and restart Credentials Manager.

Answer (score 145):

This helped me: just wait about a minute or two.

> Wait a few minutes, then retry your operation.

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms833805.aspx

Comment: I'm a software developer, dealing with this often. I can't just wait a minute or two.

Comment: Confirmed, I had waited a minute and was still getting that error, which made me nervous and brought me here. Just had to wait a couple minutes longer than I had.

Comment: Many minutes waited, many minutes wasted - I can't reboot the computer for it is doing other things. I am unhappy.

Answer (score 55):

The error message could result due to the following reason:

1. The service associated with Credential Manager does not start.
2. Some files associated with the application have gone corrupt.

Please follow the steps mentioned below to resolve the issue:

Method 1:

1. Click on the “Start”
2. In the text box that reads “Search Program and Files” type “Services”
3. Right click on “Services” and select “Run as Administrator”
4. In the Services Window, look for Credential Manager Service and “Stop” it.
5. Restart the computer and “Start” the Credential Manager Service and set it to “Automatic”.
6. Restart the computer and it should work fine.

Method 2:
1.     Run System File Checker. Refer to the link mentioned below for additional information:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833

Comment: Method 1 worked for me on Windows 10. Did not need to restart the computer.

Comment: Method 1 worked for me on Windows Server 2012 R2 without the need to restart the machine

Comment: Why would you need to stop one service (step 4) before stopping the whole OS (step 5)? In my case, simply restarting the Credential Manager was enough.

Comment: How is the Credential Manager related to IIS? (I am surprised to find that restarting the Credential Manager service did indeed allow me to start the app pool.)

Answer (score 27):

In my case, the VS debugger was attached to the w3wp process. After detaching the debugger, I was able to restart the Application Pool

Answer (score 26):

I stopped the IIS Worker Process (in task manager), and then started the IIS again.
It worked.

Answer (score 17):

I killed related w3wp.exe (on a friends' advise) at task manager and it worked.

Note: Use at your own risk. Be careful picking which one to kill.

Answer (score 7):

Restarting the machine worked for me but not every time.

If you are really stuck on this then follow below steps

1. Open Task Manager
2. A window will open. Click on Details tab.
3. Search for the process name you wanted to restart/stop.
4. Select process, right click on it, select End task option.
5. A confirmation dialog box will appear. Click on End process button.
6. Now try to restart your service from Services.msc window.

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue recently,

Problem statement:
Mine was a windows service that I run locally by attaching VS debugger. When I stop debugging and try to restart/stop the service (under services.msc) I used to get the mentioned error.

Solution:

1. Open up Task manager.
2. Search for the service (based on the exe name and not service name, for those that are different).
3. Kill the service.

On doing the above the service is stopped.

Answer (score 5):

I forgot I had mine attached to Visual Studio debugger. Be sure to disconnect from there, and then wait a moment. Otherwise killing the process viewing the PID from the Worker Processes functionality of IIS manager will work too.

Comment: Visual Studio Remote Debugger was the issue for me as well.

Comment: Same for me. Hint to find the PID of the Application Pool: Select the servername in IIS manager and then "Worker Processes" is found in the IIS-section...

Answer (score 5):

Restarting the IIS windows service (`World Wide Web Publishing Service`) and then starting the application pool has worked for me. However, as the top answer suggests it may have just been the waiting that caused it to subsequently work.

Answer (score 2):

Being impatient, I created a new App Pool with the same settings and used that.

Answer (score 2):

I kept having this problem whenever I tried to start an app pool more than once. Rather than rebooting, I simply run the *Application Information* Service. (Note: This service is set to run manually on my system, which may be the reason for the problem.) From its description, it seems obvious that it is somehow involved:

> Facilitates the running of interactive applications with additional administrative privileges.  If this service is stopped, users will be unable to launch applications with the additional administrative privileges they may require to perform desired user tasks.

Presumably, IIS manager (as well as most other processes running as an administrator) does not maintain admin privileges throughout the life of the process, but instead request admin rights from the *Application Information* service on a case-by-case basis.

Source: [social.technech.microsoft.com](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f0b9bcc1-e127-4c63-b06a-cac9517e1d4b/the-service-cannot-accept-control-messages-at-this-time?forum=winservergen#af9db870-647e-44dd-b677-d44ece97a645)

Answer (score 1):

The debugger might be attached to w3wp.exe via "attach to process" making it unable to restart.